# XCode - Swift - Facebook Authentication with Parse

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, email, parse-platform

I have Facebook authentication integrated with parse using the following code:

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
  (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if let user = user {
    if user.isNew {
      let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)

      graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        user["email"] = result.valueForKey("email") as! String
        user["firstName"] = result.valueForKey("first_name") as! String
        user["lastName"] = result.valueForKey("last_name") as! String

        user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
          // goto app
        }
      }
    } else {
      // goto app
    }
  } else {
    // Canceled
  }
}
```

So I use Parse's PFFacebookUtils to login the user, then add the extra fields email, firstName and lastName based on the user's Facebook info, then I log the user in.  Just wondering if this is the right way to go about adding those additionals fields, and I was also wondering if there was a way to stop an email confirmation from going out in this scenario?  I have a register via email option so I need email confirmation, but just not for Facebook login.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as far as I know that is the correct way to set new field. Maybe you want to check for nil in the optionals instead of explicitly unwrapping like that? 
And no I think every time you set the email on a PFUser it will send the authentication email if you have that option on in Parse.

One option to save the email without notifying them is to create your own emailId field and set it to that so that they don't get an email asking for authentication and when signing up a new user with email you can also set that field to be the same emailId (it is kind of messy cause you have the same value repeated) but its a workaround worth trying.